# IE11: How to polyfill `Array.values().next()` in Internet explorer, in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, core-js

I'm having trouble with iterators in my React project running in IE11.

Here's the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue;

```
// index.js

...
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'core-js'
import 'whatwg-fetch'
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

const a = [1,2,3,4].values().next();
console.log(a);
...
```

In IE11, I'm getting an error that says

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'next'
```

I've already imported the entire 'core-js' library, what else do I need to import to polyfill this functionality in IE11?

Answer (score 0):

put

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

as the **first two lines** in your index.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill

Comment: and also try without the ```/ie11``` in case this does not solve your problem